# Multiple shaders or multiple texture samplings?

Tags: graphics, shader, render, fragment-shader

I'm rendering a terrain, which has lots of tileable textures. I have a decision to make:
1. Use each texture separately and sample them normally (requires two passes, one vertex shader and two fragment shaders, because the max number of registers in a fragment shader isn't enough to store all the textures).
2. Batch all textures in an atlas and do one pass (requires 5 samplings in the texture for each one in the previous method, because I need to fix the tiles at the borders http://0fps.net/2013/07/09/texture-atlases-wrapping-and-mip-mapping/ )

Do anyone have a recommendation for me? Is it more expensive to do two passes of fragment shaders (I can probably discard many of the pixels in one or in the other pass) or doing 5 times more texture sampling but in a single pass?

I know there's no ready answer, I'm just looking for a recommendation out of experience.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just use [array textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) like the article recommends. Most GPUs nowadays should support them.

Comment: I'm using Ogre3d, and I'm using its Low Level material, which doesn't support Array Textures, I'm using array textures in other objects in my scene, but for the terrain I can't use it, at least not right now.